# Interpretation model with logarithm and square root

Tags: interpretation

How do I interpret this model:

$$
Price = -7.095 - 9.471[\ln(Number Of Different Kinds Of Fruits)] + 53.942 \sqrt{Number Of Customer} + ...
$$

Is that:

- If there are no kinds of fruits nor visitors nor other variables, the expected average price will be -7.095
- If the natural logarithm of Number Of Different Kinds Of Fruits increases with one and all other things remain the same, the expected average price will decrease with 9.471
- If there is one extra customer and all other variables remain the same, the average expected price will increase with 53.942

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems peculiar that such a complex model was selected instead of a more simple linear model. However, if you insist on using that model then notice that *NumberOfDifferentKindsOfFruits* should be strictly greater than 0.

Further:

If *NumberOfDifferentKindsOfFruits* equals 1 and *NumberOfCustomer* equals 0 the expected average price will be -7.095.

If the natural logarithm of *NumberOfDifferentKindsOfFruits* increases by one (that is to say that *NumberOfDifferentKindsOfFruits* is almost tripled) and all other things remain the same, the expected average price will decrease with 9.471.

If the *square root* of the *NumberOfCustomer* is increased by one and all other variables remain the same, the average expected price will increase with 53.942. Notice, that the last remark is not easily to be understood in terms of the single *NumberOfCustomer* variable without square root.

Hope that the above will help you

Comment: Thank you. This isn't a real world model, it's just to help me understand things.